# hibernate exception: transaction roll back failed

Tags: java, mysql, swing, hibernate

When im running my hibernate project in java swing, it works at first. but when i wait for some time and i recieve error like  org.hibernate.TransactionException: rollback failed.. tell me a solution for this.

Here is my error

```
Aug 16, 2013 10:52:21 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08S01
Aug 16, 2013 10:52:21 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: Communications link failure
The last packet successfully received from the server was 89,371 milliseconds ago. 
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 1 milliseconds ago.
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" org.hibernate.TransactionException: rollback  failed
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.rollback(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:215) at com.softroniics.queenpharma.services.PurchaseOrderService.showAllPurchase(PurchaseOrderService.java:131)
```

Here is my hibernate cfg file

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?> 
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD  3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://queenpharma.db.11583306.hostedresource.com/queenpharma</property>
    <property name="connection.username">queenpharma</property>
    <property name="connection.password">Queenpharma#1</property>
    <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="connection.autocommit">false</property>

    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">1</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">0</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">5000</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">1000</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">300</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">1</property>

    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>
    <mapping class="com.softroniics.queenpharma.model.LoginModel" />
    <mapping class="com.softroniics.queenpharma.model.PurchaseCompanyModel" />
```

---- and so on------

here is some my code

```
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    StockModel stockModel = null;
    try {
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        Iterator<StockModel> iterator = session
                .createQuery("FROM StockModel where productid='" + id + "'")
                .list().iterator();
        if(iterator.hasNext()){
        stockModel = iterator.next();
        }

    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        if (tx != null)
            tx.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
         session.close();
```

Comment: please... any one help me....

Comment: Why is your connection pool of size 1?

Comment: then what can i set as pool size??

Comment: 1 is ok for testing purpose

Comment: @ShakeebManjeri Have you tried removing default connection pool size property???

Comment: yess .. I tried it.. but no change..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error code you get `SQLState: 08S01` suggests that the host name that you use for the database is incorrect according to [Mapping MySQL Error Numbers to JDBC SQLState Codes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/connector-j-reference-error-sqlstates.html).

So first please make sure that the database host: `queenpharma.db.11583306.hostedresource.com` is spelled correctly.

If the error persists please modify your exception handler to catch the exception caused by the rollback statement like below so you are able to understand what caused the rollback in the first place.

*Note: you should do this only for troubleshooting this issue. You do not want to shallow any exceptions when in a production environment*

```
} catch (HibernateException e) {
    if (tx != null) {
        try {
            tx.rollback();
        } catch(Exception re) {
            System.err.println("Error when trying to rollback transaction:"); // use logging framework here
            re.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    System.err.println("Original error when executing query:"); // // use logging framework here

    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: printStackTrace() function is a security problem. Usage of it is never suggested. Instead you should log you errors to database!

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the issue with Mysql connection time out, Guess there would be default time out for Mysql. Refer this article might help you [Hibernate Broken pipe](http://vatsalad.wordpress.com/2010/09/28/hibernate-communications-link-error-c3p0mysql-and-broken-pipe-error/)

**UPDATE**
   From the hibernate documents

> Hibernate's own connection pooling algorithm is, however, quite
>   rudimentary. It is  intended to help you get started and is not
>   intended for use in a production system, or even for performance
>   testing. You should use a third party pool for best performance and
>   stability. **Just replace the hibernate.connection.pool_size property
>   with connection pool specific settings. This will turn off Hibernate's
>   internal pool**. For example, you might like to use c3p0.

So you no need to specify the hibernate connection pool size property when you are using c3p0 connection pooling

Answer (score 0):

Remember committing and closing the session. It might will be that you do not commit and Hibernate tries a rollback after the connection has already timed out.

It would be helpful to see how you access the DB, please post some code.